# Recording Unsubscribes without Unsubscribing?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

Scenario: We have a custom subscription center that is handling all subscriber preferences. 'Unsubscribing' from a communication type (or all communications) is actually managed by a Data Extension field as opposed to the status held at the All Subscribers / List / Publication List level.

With that in mind, is it still possible to record an unsubscribe in tracking, even though the unsubscribe isn't directly tied to the subscriber status? I've used the AMPscript log unsub event before, and was thinking of using that again, but can't think of the best way to implement.

At the moment I'm thinking of running the unsub log event whenever a subscriber 'unsubscribes', and then to resubscribe them immediately with more AMPScript - but I'm not a big fan of how unsubscribing at the All Subscribers level unsubscribes you from all account lists (even though lists aren't currently used in this account).

If anybody has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want the All Subs status updated to correspond with the Data Extension? You could update All Subs and keep it in sync with the Data Extension. Or, create a Tracking Data Extension of your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Just because of the way the account is set up, multi-branded within a single business unit, where even if you 'unsubscribe from all' you're not really unsubscribing from all. Custom tracking is an option too, just not overly ideal because it wouldn't interact with Discover.

Comment: Ah...gotcha. If only Discover let you report on Data Extensions, that would be awesome.

Comment: Yes reporting on Data Extensions is really lacking overall when compared to lists - I guess it makes sense given the different nature of the two but it would be nice to have!